# R shiny puzzling warning: Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I have written a shiny app that permits the user to amend individual rows of a dataframe but when I try to include an option to append new rows I get this warning on the console:

> Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON.

and in a text input box that should contain an item from one column of the data frame the following appears instead:

```
[object Object]
```

There are a few answers here that refer to the warning message but in different conditions than apply in my case, and they appear to have little in common with each other apart from the warning message.

Here is my app for amending the dataframe. It works perfectly.

```
require(shiny)

in.df <- data.frame(name = c("Alice","Bob","Charles"), 
                age = c(22, 25, 36))
rownames(in.df) <- NULL
runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      sidebarPanel( 
        numericInput("line", "Line number", value = 1),
        textInput("name", "Name:"),
        numericInput("age", "Age:", value = 25),
        actionButton("amendButton", "Amend an entry") 
  ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("table"))
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session){
      values <- reactiveValues()
      values$df <- in.df
      current_line <- reactive({
        il <- input$line
        nr <- nrow(values$df)
        if(il > nr){
          return(nr) 
        } else if(il <= 0){
          return(1) 
        } else{
          return(il) 
        } 
      })
      amendData <- observe({
        if(input$amendButton > 0){
          newLine <- isolate(c(input$name, input$age))
          values$df <- isolate(values$df[-  current_line(), ])
          isolate(values$df <-   rbind(as.matrix(values$df), unlist(newLine)))
          values$df <- values$df[order(values$df[,1]),]  
        }
      })

      observe({
        updateTextInput(session = session,
                        inputId = 'name', 
                        value =   values$df[unlist( current_line()),1]
        )
        updateNumericInput(session = session,
                           inputId = 'age', 
                           value = values$df[unlist( current_line()),2]
        )
        updateNumericInput(session = session ,
                           inputId = 'line', 
                           value =  current_line()
        )

      })
      output$table <- renderTable(values$df )
    }
  )
)
```

It seemed to me that it would be a simple matter to add an 'append' option in the following way:

1. Add a new action button

   `actionButton("appendButton", "Append an entry")`
2. Include a corresponding handler that can be very similar indeed to the handler for the `addButton`:

   ```
   addData <- observe({
        if(input$appendButton > 0){
          newLine <- isolate(c(input$name,    input$age)) 
          isolate(values$df <-  rbind(as.matrix(values$df), unlist(newLine)))
          values$df <- values$df[order(values$df[,1]),]
        }
      })
   ```

The only difference of substance between the two handlers is that the new one does not need the line

```
values$df <- isolate(values$df[-  current_line(), ])
```

because in the append case no old row is being removed.

But it does not work: I get the warning and the odd change to the text input box that I described.

Answer (score 1):

In shiny 1.6 I got a running app after I changed `amendData <- observe` to `amendData <- observeEvent`. Otherwise the code got stuck in an infinite loop.

However, in order to be able to add new rows I had to change reactive value `current_line`. The code always resets it to an existing row so that one can never add new entries.

I had changed `current_line` so that it also allowed it to be `nrow + 1` and cleared the numeric input fields when `current_line` was larger than the number of rows.

*Now, I finally saw the situation that was described in the question.*

It was caused by `values$df <- rbind(as.matrix(values$df), unlist(newLine))`. R added the new row with a name. The named rows of the data frame seemed to be the problem when sent to the UI. My guess is that this is a problem deeply buried in the reactive messaging system of Shiny.

```
require(shiny)

in.df <- data.frame(name = c("Alice","Bob","Charles"), 
                    age = c(22L, 25L, 36L))
rownames(in.df) <- NULL

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      sidebarPanel( 
        numericInput("line", "Line number", value = 1),
        textInput("name", "Name:"),
        numericInput("age", "Age:", value = 25),
        actionButton("amendButton", "Amend an entry") 
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("table"))
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session){
      values <- reactiveValues()
      values$df <- in.df
      
      current_line <- reactive({
        il <- req(input$line)
        nr <- nrow(values$df)
        if(il > nr){
          return(nr+1)
        } else if (il <= 0){
          return(1) 
        } else {
          return(il) 
        } 
      })
      
      amendData <- observeEvent(input$amendButton, {
          isolate({
            newLine   <- c(input$name, as.numeric(input$age))
            values$df <- values$df[- current_line(), ]
            values$df <- rbind(values$df, unname(newLine))
          })
          values$df <- values$df[order(values$df[,1]),]
      })
      
      observe({
          updateNumericInput(session = session, inputId = 'line', 
                             value =  current_line())

        if (current_line() <= nrow(values$df)) {
          updateNumericInput(session = session, inputId = 'age', 
                             value = values$df[current_line(), 2])
          updateTextInput(session = session, inputId = 'name', 
                          value =   values$df[current_line(), 1])
        }
        else {
          updateNumericInput(session = session, inputId = 'age', value = "")
          updateNumericInput(session = session, inputId = 'name', value =  "")
        }
      })
        
      output$table <- renderTable( values$df )
    }
  )
)
```